# web api not returning all objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a method in my web api controller which looks like this:

```
// GET api/categories/top
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/categories/top")]
public IHttpActionResult Top()
{
    var models = service.GetRoot("Categories", "Assets").Categories;
    var t = models.Where(model => !model.Deleted);

    return Ok(t);
}
```

if I run that, I get the first item fine, but the others are displayed as

`{"$ref":"3"},{"$ref":"13"},{"$ref":"14"},{"$ref":"15"}`

If I change my code to:

```
// GET api/categories/top
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/categories/top")]
public IHttpActionResult Top()
{
    var models = service.GetRoot("Categories", "Assets").Categories;

    return Ok(models);
}
```

it works fine (but this shows all categories including deleted categories which is not what I want).

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: First inspect the contents of t in debug.  If it looks ok, call it via a browser and have a look in developer tools at what goes over the wire.

Comment: please provide example data for *what you have* and *what you want*, Do you want your output to only be `{"$ref":"3"}` assuming for this value the "Deleted" flag is false.

Answer (score 0):

What about that?

```
var models = service.GetRoot("Categories", "Assets").Categories;
var t = models.Where(model => !model.Deleted).ToList();
return Ok(t);
```

I expect that there is a problem returning a not executed IEnumerable object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example for the same

### Class

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

### Sample Data

```
var employees = new List<Employee>();
employees.Add(new Employee{ Name = "Yasser", Deleted = false });
employees.Add(new Employee{ Name = "Hanselman", Deleted = true });
employees.Add(new Employee{ Name = "Neel", Deleted = true });
employees.Add(new Employee{ Name = "Ian", Deleted = false });
```

### Return "Not deleted" List

```
return employees.Where(model => !model.Deleted).ToList();
```

### Change required in your code:

```
// GET api/categories/top
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/categories/top")]
public IHttpActionResult Top()
{
    var models = service.GetRoot("Categories", "Assets").Categories;
    var t = models.Where(model => !model.Deleted).ToList();
    return Ok(t);
}
```